# How to have sub_directory use VCPKG in find_package() in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build PROJ from source.  I don't have many of its dynamic dependencies on Centos 7, nor is it possible for me to obtain these dependencies through the system package manager.

In order to skirt these issues, I sought to use VCPKG.  However VCPKG is in a **lot** of turmoil over PROJ and I cannot physically use any version past 7.2.x in VCPKG (I need newer features) and I can't load geo tiffs either (so most non trivial projections will straight up not work). So I can't use VCPKG and PROJ together *at all*.

However I can still comfortably get the dependencies required to run PROJ through VCPKG.

I tried to convert PROJ source into a subdirectory, however to my suprise it was still trying to use my system libraries despite `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=... -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux` being set.

I tried using the directory as a standalone library, but with the VCPKG variables set, and... it worked.

So I tried setting cache variables to see if somehow that wasn't propagated downwards, and it didn't work (error message same as below)

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/home/user/Documents/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "TEST")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-linux" CACHE STRING "TEST")
add_subdirectory(external/PROJ)
```

My project is setup like this:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- main.cpp
- external
    - PROJ 
        ...
```

my cmake is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(external/PROJ)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE PROJ::proj)
```

and I keep getting

```
-- Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so
-- Sqlite3 version: 3.7.17
CMake Error at external/PROJ/CMakeLists.txt:180 (message):
  sqlite3 >= 3.11 required!
```

when PROJ is a subdirectory

and I get the correct thing:

```
-- Found Sqlite3: /home/user/Documents/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsqlite3.a
-- Sqlite3 version: 3.36.0
```

when I don't use it as a sub-directory.

Comment: You are trying to do some package management from CMake, which it isn't intended for. Having said that, you're not the first being seduced by the idea. See https://hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating-new/create/cmake.html for others who are in to this although from another angle.

As for your specific problem, have you provided all source for the CMake files? It's hard to see the problem from what I can see. Do you have a link to any repository with your code?

Comment: @Mats  I have zero ability show you the code, it simply can't happen. however, what I provided should allow you to completely reproduce this problem (though I think your point was about X,Y problems, not reproducibility?). I'm not sure what you mean by "have you provided all source for the CMake files".  PROJ is the cloned repo for https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ, so by definition it has all the source.  CLone proj into a sub_directory, install dependencies for proj in VCPKG, use the cmake arguments and cmake file, you should see the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After the first `project()` call, it is *much* too late for `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to do anything useful. Indeed, it won't even be *read* if it changes after the first `project()` call. Vcpkg, Conan, and the like must be used globally or not at all.

You could get away with writing something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21) # upgrade!! 3.13 is ancient

# Use vcpkg by default
if (EXISTS "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
  set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      CACHE STRING "TEST")
  set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-linux"
      CACHE STRING "default vcpkg triplet")
endif ()

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17
    CACHE STRING "C++ standard to use")

if (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD LESS 17)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Must compile `test` with C++17 or newer")
endif ()

add_subdirectory(external/PROJ)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE PROJ::proj)
```

It is customary to set the environment variable `VCPKG_ROOT` to point to your vcpkg installation.

Comment: Why do the command line arguments for the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE and VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET CMake not propagate through already?  Infact, if I put message() stuff in the subdirectory, the values are the same, but it still doesn't force the directory to use the toolchain for whatever reason.

Comment: Alright, finally got a chance to try this out.  It doesn't work. Library still tries to use system install instead of VCPKG, even though my main project uses vcpkg fine.

Comment: I even set it *in subdirectories PROJ/CMakeLists.txt*, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I said in my answer that setting it in a subdirectory will never work, by design

Comment: Can you post a _full_ reproducible example?

Comment: What else do you need? The above reproduces this for me.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out, VCPKG was leaving a "ghost" target hanging around, so I was trying to build against that, and it was majorly screwing everything up, deleting debug and release folders for building fixed the issue, and made it use the appropriate targets, now I don't need to manually cache anything, the command line works.

Comment: @Krupip Glad you got it working! By "full" I meant the exact sequence of commands you used to get the error.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69546764/2036035) and wondering why it *still* wasn't working, I tried making an exact copy of the current MCVE in a different directory. To my surprise, it ***worked***, and even worked with out caching (normal CMake command line variables).  When using PROJ as a `sub_directory`, it actually only exposes `PROJ` as a target.  However, I was trying to use `PROJ::proj`, a target apparently made by VCPKG to link against *their* install.  Well I had uninstalled that, and wasn't using it as a dependency.  Despite that, left over files *in a separate build folder* apparently were messing with my install, my directory originally looked like this:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- main.cpp
- external
    - PROJ 
- cmake-build-debug
- cmake-build-release
```

Well, VCPKG stores some meta information about package caches and such in these directories.  But with out *completely deleting the whole directory* I was not able to get it to "forget" about this old install.  What's more, it took deleting *both* directories to get it to "fully" forget about proj.

So I deleted these files, like this:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- main.cpp
- external
    - PROJ
```

And reset/reloaded the CMake cache and file, and re-generated those build directories.

After doing this, I no longer had to worry about this extra target.